# Some general questions about deformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, complex-manifolds

$\newcommand{\spec}[1]{\mathrm{spec}(#1)}$
$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}$
$\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}$

These days I am reading in Kurke, Pfister, Roczen "Henselsche Ringe und algebraische Geometrie" the chapter 5. "Approximation theory and algebraization of Deformations" especially "5.7 Infinitesimal deformations of affine schemata" and "5.8 Infinitesimal deformations of proper schemata."

Thinking about deformations in general I came to some questions, which are so general, that I could not find a way to resolve them by googling key phrases (and only partially by looking into Hartshorne's Springer GTM book on Deformation theory).

1. If one starts with a variety (or an algebraic scheme = of finite type and separated over $k$) $X_0/k$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ and considers all mathematically interesting/mostly studied families of deformations $f:X \to S$, that is flat morphisms $f$ with
   $f^{-1}(s_0) = X_0$ for a closed point $s_0 \in S$, what can one say about the $S$ chosen as base?

1a). Of course $S = \spec{A}$ with $A$ Artin ring over $k$, especially $A = k[t]/(t^n)$, also $A=k[[t]]$ and $A=k[[t_1,\ldots,t_r]]$ (with $r = \dim_k \mathrm{Ext}^1(\Omega_{X_0|k}, \mathcal{O}_{X_0})$ occur naturally, but what are typical non-local $S$?

1b). Is it more usual to have $S$ that are themselves nonsingular or are for global deformations singular $S$ sometimes "better" or "enforced"?

1c). If only $X_0/k$ is given initially, does there exist a "best" or "canonical" $S$, which is to $X_0$ like the domain of holomorphic continuation to the germ of a holomorphic function?

1d). Can such an $S$ or $f:X \to S$ be concretely computed, say from equations $f_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ giving $X_0$ as an affine or projective scheme?

2. If $X_0$ is proper over $k$ and one considers deformations $f:X \to S$ of $X_0$ non-singular with $X$ non-singular over $k$, then $f_V:X - f^{-1}(V) \to S - V$ is smooth for a closed subset $V \subseteq S$. So if $k=\CC$ the map $f_V$ is a proper submersion and by Ehresmann's fibration theorem a fibration (of manifolds).

2a). Can/Should $S$ be chosen, starting from a given $X_0$, so that $V = \{ s_1,\ldots, s_r\}$ is finite set of points of $S$?

2b). Do the singular fibers $X_{s_i}$ determine $f:X \to S$ in this case totally?

2c). What is the relation between the homology groups
$H_p(X_s, \ZZ)$ and $H_p(X_{s_i},\ZZ)$ for $s \notin V$ (replace $\ZZ$ by $\QQ,\CC$)?

2d). The image of a map $\gamma:[0,1] \to S - V$ can be covered by patches $U_i \subseteq S$ with $f^{-1}(U_i) = U_i \times F$. The transition maps define a map $H_p(X_{\gamma(0)}, \ZZ) \to H_p(X_{\gamma(1)})$. How concretely can these maps be computed with a computer algebra system?

3. What if one asks, given a deformation $f:X \to S$ of $X_0/k$ whether an "object" associated with $X_0$ can be deformed along $f$ and in how many ways?

3a) Say $\mathcal{F}_0$ is a vector bundle on $X_0$. How can one compute the space of all vector bundles $\mathcal{F}$ of $X$, flat over $S$, that have $i_0^*(\mathcal{F}) = \mathcal{F}_0$, where $i_0:\spec{k} \to S$ and $X_0 = i_0^*(X)$?
Can one compute its dimension from some $\mathrm{Ext}$ or $H^p(X_0,-)$ groups, at least, when $X_0$ and $X$ are proper/projective over $S$?

3b) Another "object" would be a closed immersion $g_0:X_0 \to \mathbb{P}_k^N$. Can one compute whether there is an extension of $g_0$ to a closed immersion $g:X \to \mathbb{P}_S^N$? How to compute such an extension explicitly? How many extensions exist?

3c) An extension of 3b would be: Say we have to deformations $f:X \to S$ of $X_0$ and $g:Y \to S$ of $Y_0$ and a closed immersion $h_0:X_0 \to Y_0$. In how many ways can $h_0$ be extended to a closed immersion $h:X \to Y$ over $S$? Can one compute from explicit cohomology groups a criterion whether such an $h$ exists?

Please excuse that this question violates the norms for questions at mathoverflow probably in many ways, but I do not have the possibility to ask them to someone knowledgeable in a personal conversation, which would be surely more appropriate.

So I am happy with any partial answer and also, of course, with links to surveys (preferably accessible over the internet), which would give me a more advanced standpoint, from which I could put these questions into position and perhaps answer them myselves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 3b) should be controlled by H^1(X, pullback of Tangent sheaf to P^N) and 3a) by Ext^(F, F) if S is dual numbers (always first case to check!) For various parts of two google "nearby/ vanishing cycles", nb that re 2b) u also have to worry about monodromy action on cohom of generic (smooth) fiber. 1c) google "versal deformation space"

Comment: In general my advice would be (re building intuition about def problems) to compute as many examples over $S=spec k[\epsilon] $ as u can. eg do associative algebras, Lie algebras to "discover" hochschild cohom and chevalley eilenberg cochains respectively.